# Starting an external activity, getting permission error

Tags: android

I'm trying to start the preferences activity in the native messenger client from my application.  in AOSP Mms.apk does not have an intent filter setup on that activity.  Regardless I'm trying to find a work around to launch the user into that screen.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.MessagingPreferenceActivity"));
    intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    try {
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppUtils.alertError(this, error);
    }
```

I'm receiving

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.MessagingPreferenceActivity } from ProcessRecord{406e2738 674:com.handmark.genericapp/10034} (pid=674, uid=10034) requires null
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. That activity is not exported (at least in the source code showing in Google Code Search), so you cannot start it, except by rewriting the app as part of your own custom firmware.

Also, bear in mind that this app may or may not exist on any given device.

Comment: This is what I was thinking as well, was hoping there was a workaround.  I'm aware it may not exist, I check for the existence of this activity in another area.

Comment: @Tyler: "was hoping there was a workaround" -- I sure hope not. The notion that every activity has to be a public API is scary.